# Example of critical (non-relativistic) quantum field theory in 1D?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, phase-transition, critical-phenomena

Is there an example of a critical non-relativistic bosonic quantum field theory in 1D (no time)? So, the field theory can be describe by annihilation, $\psi(x)$, and creation operators, $\psi^\dagger(x)$, and there is some critical value for a parameter of the Hamiltonian, $\mathcal{H}(\psi,\psi^\dagger)$? The simpler the example the better!